# Git restructure commits

Tags: git, version-control

I have the following scenario

Branch A: c1, c2
Branch B: c1, c2, c3, c4
Branch D: c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6

Now, branch D was meant to branch from Branch A, but I mistakenly branched from branch B.  The commits, c5 and c6 are not related to commits, C3 and c4.

How do I go about making a new Branch, E, from Branch A, and moving just commits C5 and C6 over to this new branch such that it is structured like this:

Branch E: c1, c2, c5, c6

Comment: A commit ID changes depending on its parents. You can use `git rebase` to relatively easily create branch E with c1, c2, c5', and c6'; you cannot have *the exact same* commits with different parents. That means the SHA will change, etc.

Comment: @DanielH can you give me an example of how to do this with git rebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Option 1:

If you really only have 2 commits to move you can do:

```
git checkout -b E A
git cherry-pick c5
git cherry-pick c6
```

## Option 2:

But `git rebase` let's you do multiple commits at a time:

```
gut checkout -b E D
git rebase --onto A B
```

First, we start a new branch E at D. Then the rebase syntax is to take everything in E "since B" and recommit it "onto" A.

### Variations / Options

- You can use the `-i` flag for interactive and you should only see commits c5 and c6 in the "todo".
- Technically, the last argument of the rebase defaults to the branch you're in, but you could explicitly call it out (E), which helps if you are not already on it.

Comment: With Option 1, that will change branch A. Wouldn't `git checkout -b E A` be better?

Comment: @DanielH, you're right - I was thinking more about moving the commits than naming the branch. Fixing now.

Comment: Thanks.  I did end up using git rebase --onto (i messed it up twice before doing it successfully though).... also never knew about the cherry pick option, but I had too many commits for that